# How to set a element's z-index higher than it appended neighbor

Tags: css, reactjs, highcharts

I am working on a chart that show a tooltip when hover on it. Inside the ring, there is a board showing current total status.

I am able to make that tooltip non-transparent when it appear on top of the pie chart slice.

**However, it appear as transparent when it overlay with the inner diagram** (as below)

[image]

I understand this may seem to stupid to ask, but I have been struggling to make it non-transparent when it overlay with the inner diagram.

Any idea that I can make the tooltip non blocked by the inner div?

**In the code structure:  The highchart(pie chart and tooltip is also part of it) is stacking on the ChartInnerStatus**

So, I think that's the reason why the tooltip is under the inner status.

```
<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
      <ChartInnerStatus
        customAssetAllocations={customAssetAllocationsToGrid}
      ></ChartInnerStatus>
```

What I did is to set tooltips 'z-index': 500, position as relative to make it on top of the inner status again.

**But I got this error,** even I set it position as relative.

**I understand that parent can never cover its child, but tooltips would only appear when hovering. Is it still able to make it cover  its child?**

Is there way to make the inner status below the tooltip when tooltip appear or way to make that inner circle transparent so that it shows the element behind it??

[image]

Comment: I understand that parent can never cover its child, but tooltips would only appear when hovering. Is it still able to make it cover its child?